# Como usar parametro de função como atributo de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, react, ecmascript-6

Olá!

Afim de reutilizar uma função estou realizando o seguinte procedimento:

View 1 tem este obj:

```
  obj: [
  {"fruta": "maça", "valor1":1},
  {"fruta": "banana", "valor1":1},
  {"fruta": "pera", "valor1":1}
  ]
```

a View 2 tem este objeto:

```
obj: [
  {"trufa": "chocolate", "preço":1},
  {"trufa": "doce de leite", "preço":1},
  {"trufa": "nutela", "preço":1}
  ]
```

a View 3 tem este:

```
  obj: [
      {"carro": "uno", "avaliado":12222},
      {"carro": "gol", "avaliado":133333},
      {"carro": "jetta", "avaliado":133333}
      ]
```

eu fiz uma função que tranforma esses objetos:

```
function tranforma(data, titulo, id){

let obj1 = {}
let obj2 = []

data.map(item => {
 //aqui esta meu erro, preciso fazer isso, mas nao sei como:
 obj1.titulo = item."AQUI SERA O QUE VIER EM TITULO"
 obj1.value = item."AQUI SERA O QUE VIER EM ID"

 obj2.push(obj1);
});

return obj2;

}
```

nas views eu chamo a função passando o obj, o nome do atributo titulo e o o nome do atributo valor, pois ambos variam de acordo com o obj.

**Resultado esperado:**

No final de tudo, sempre quando eu chamar a função transforma ele irá retornar para min um array de objetos com titulo e valor, contidos no data

Comment: Mas os parametros de `tranforma` são para aplicar a todos os elementos do `data` ? Ou apenas a um ? Na minha otica seria mais facil exemplificar com o resultado que espera de `obj2` no fim do `map` correr.

Comment: Mude `item."AQUI SERA O QUE VIER EM TITULO"` para `item[titulo]`, é isso? `push` é uma função para array, você está tentando chama-la em um objeto, não irá funcionar

Comment: Tem razão, reformulei a pergunta

Comment: Guilherme resolveu item[titulo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O uso de colchetes (`[ ]`) para acessar variáveis já tinha sido respondido aqui no site (se não me engano eu mesmo respondi), mas não achei a pergunta para linkar, quanto ao seu código, algumas dicas:

- Criar uma variável "temporária" para criar um objeto é desnecessário, poderia simplesmente fazer:

  ```
  obj2.push({
      titulo: item[titulo],
      value: item[id]
  });
  ```
- Se você está usando `map` pode alterar os seus valores e retornar o resultado da função:

  ```
  function tranforma(data, titulo, id){
      return data.map(item => {
          return {
              titulo: item[titulo],
              value: item[id]
          }
      });
  }
  ```